# In Scala is it possible to retrieve the `val` referenced by a singleton type?

Tags: scala, types, dependent-type

I'm trying to get a minimal form of dependent types in Scala. If I have

```
class A[T <: Int]

val x: Int = 7
```

I can

```
val a = new A[x.type]
```

Now is it possible to recover `x` from its singleton `x.type`?

Or, if that's not possible, is it possible to associate a stable identifier with a type somehow, and then extract it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't recover `x` from `x.type` because of JVM type erasure. For example, how would this be implemented?

```
def f[A]: A = ???
f[x.type]
```

At the JVM bytecode level, there's no way that `f` can find value `x: A` given `A = x.type` because it doesn't have anything to work with: all type parameters are lost at run-time, and anyway, the `x` value is not available on `f`'s parameter stack.

For the same reason, to get a stable-ID of a type, you'd have to reify it as a `Manifest` value. But when I tried, I get a strange result,

```
def f[A : Manifest] = implicitly[Manifest[A]]
val x = "hi"
val y = "ho"
println(f[x.type]) // hi.type
println(f[y.type]) // ho.type
f[x.type] == f[y.type] // true !?
```

I'm not sure why these two type manifests are equal---they even have different `toString` representations. Could this be a Scala bug? *Update*: According to the [ScalaDoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.Manifest), *The type-relation operators <:< and =:= should be considered approximations only, as there are numerous aspects of type conformance which are not yet adequately represented in manifests.*

To summarize, the reification of type information into run-time values doesn't happen automatically on the JVM. Scala's `Manifest` is supposed to fill the gap, but I guess it doesn't work with dependent types.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there any conceivable way to encode a value at the type level? I'm working with a library (squeryl) that uses reflection and makes decisions based on types.

Comment: Depends what you mean by encode. In a certain sense, `x.type` *does* encode the value `x`, even though this value cannot be reified at run-time from the type alone. Also, I'm not sure how reflection (run-time inspection of values) corresponds to type level encoding. Do you mean `classOf[T]`? Sorry, I'm not familiar with squeryl. Maybe you can give a more specific question?

Comment: Squeryl inspects the types of fields and decides appropriate database columns. So "field type", which should really be a value, is moved up to the type level. I supposed I may try and solve my problem by bringing things back to the value level.

Comment: Yeah, for that use case, you have to deal with the limitations of the JVM. The JVM provides only the "class type" of the field, so, for example, `List[Int]` gets shortened to just `List`. Also, the JVM knows nothing about things like dependent types.

Comment: This answer is obsolete. TypeTag should supercedes Manifest everywhere

Answer (score 3):

To answer your second question, "associating a stable identifier to a type", one way to do it is to use type classes. Let's say I want to associate a string description to types, I can do it as follows:

```
trait Tag[A] {
  val desc : String
}

implicit object StringTag extends Tag[String] {
  val desc = "character string"
}

implicit object IntTag extends Tag[Int] {
  val desc = "32-bit integer"
}
```

Now, to recover such tags, enter the implicit magic:

```
def printTag[T : Tag] {
  val tag = implicitly[Tag[T]]
  println("Type is described as : " + tag.desc)
}
```

E.g:

```
printTag[String] // prints "Type is described as : character string"
printTag[Double] // compile-time error: no implicit value found of type Tag[Double]
```

You can even generate tags as needed, using implicit functions. For instance:

```
implicit def liftTagToList[T : Tag] = new Tag[List[T]] {
  val underlying = implicitly[Tag[T]].desc
  val desc = "list of " + underlying + "s"
}
```

I can now do the following:

```
// prints "Type is described as : list of character strings"
printTag[List[String]]
```

and even:

```
// prints "Type is described as : list of list of character stringss"
printTag[List[List[String]]]
```

Please forgive the pluralization.

Comment: Note that you can even customize the compile-time error that occurs if no implicit value is found (as in the case of Double above), using the [implicitNotFound](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.annotation.implicitNotFound) annotation on the Tag trait.

Comment: Very nice. I realized this won't help me with Squeryl since it's actually inspecting the class not the type, but I'll keep this trick in mind.